# How do I get a clean sorted and filtered routing table from Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, routes, window

I want to be able to see a simple sorting of my Windows 10 routing table. I'm trying to debug a subnet conflict between a couple VPNs I have running at the same time and the routing table makes my eyes hurt as I try to review my changes. Can I simply show routes that aren't default (going to 0.0.0.0 next hop) and then only the fields I think are relevant?

Oh and I only want to see the IPv4 routes. IPv6 isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

This command should provide you with what you're looking for.

```
Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv4 -State Alive |
Where-Object {$_.NextHop -ne '0.0.0.0'} |
Sort-Object InterfaceAlias |
Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias,DestinationAddress,DestinationPrefix,NextHop
```

**Explanation:**

`Get-NetRoute` outputs one object per route. We're using `-AddressFamily` to only get the IPv4 routes and as `-State` to assure it is an active route. Then we're piping those objects into `Where-Object` where we filter to just routes with a NextHop that isn't 0.0.0.0.

The remaining objects are passed to `Sort-Object` so they are listed by interface and then `Select-Object` to select the attributes we wish to see. I think InterfaceAlias, DestinationAddress, DestinationPrefix, NextHop are most helpful in typical debug work.

**Bonus:**

You can create a simple powershell function and place it in your profile.ps1 (Location stored as $PROFILE) to save your sanity.

```
function Get-RoutesV4 { 
  Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv4 -State Alive | Where-Object {$_.NextHop -ne '0.0.0.0'} | Sort-Object InterfaceAlias | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias,DestinationAddress,DestinationPrefix,NextHop 
}

function Get-RoutesV6 { 
  Get-NetRoute -AddressFamily IPv6 -State Alive | Where-Object {$_.NextHop -ne '0.0.0.0'} | Sort-Object InterfaceAlias | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias,DestinationAddress,DestinationPrefix,NextHop 
}

function Get-Routes { 
  Get-NetRoute -State Alive | Where-Object {$_.NextHop -ne '0.0.0.0'} | Sort-Object InterfaceAlias | Select-Object -Property InterfaceAlias,DestinationAddress,DestinationPrefix,NextHop 
}
```

Comment: as `mklement0` pointed out, _your 1st code example **will not run** as posted_. PLEASE, only post code that is valid.

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for your suggestions. Is the edited version better? The code doesn't work when pasted into Windows Terminal, but does in PowerShell so I guess that's just a bug it WinTerminal.

Comment: @Josiah: Actually, there's one more - important - improvement you can make: Replace `Format-Table` with `Select-Object`, so that the output is suitable for _further programmatic processing_. The `Format-*` cmdlets are solely for _display_ output.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Are my changes suitable?

Comment: @Josiah - yes, quite nice - easy to read and it will actually run. thanks for fixing that ... [*grin*]